# How to enable remote login for mysql.?

Tags: mysql

I have two nodes: `node1` and `node2`. I want to access MySQL installed on `node1` from `node2`.

I have so far tried using `grant all privileges on *.* to 'mysql'@'node2.openstacklocal' with grant option;` on MySQL but I still get the below error:

> ```
> ===ERROR===
> [mysql@node2 ~]$ mysql -p -h mgmt.openstacklocal  -u mysql  -P 3306
> Enter password: 
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql'@'node2.openstacklocal' (using password: YES)
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score -1):

I guess I got the solution

1. Login to mysql
2. Run command 
   `grant all on mysql.* to '<remoteuser>'@'node2.openstacklocal' identified by 'password';`

Note - Notice this command is missing word 'privileges'

Comment: (a) The `PRIVILEGES` token is optional and does not change the meaning (consult [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_all) rather than randomly guessing); removing it did nothing. (b) Granting permissions to a remote user called "root" to the `mysql` database is remarkably stupid. (c) That hostname is invalid. I fail to see how this could be the solution to anything.

Comment: What will you do if you do not have access to mysql machine, and wants to access mysql from root ? No question is stupid, it is the person who do not understands it.

Comment: This is not "mysql machine" (whatever that is), or "mysql", this is _the `mysql` database_, a specific database inside your MySQL server that stores metadata. Giving root access to that remotely is not just a terrible idea, it's also not what your question asked about.

Comment: Dude this is just an example- To give access to a user (root in this case).

Comment: I have explained twice why it is not an example of what you think it is. I can't help it if you don't listen. I am also not your "dude". Good luck.